# C# TCP Asynchronous connection actively refused with low CPU utilization

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, amazon-ec2

I have a C# TCP Asynchronous socket server.

Testing locally, I can accept 5K connections over 35 seconds. I am running a quad core hyper threaded PC (8 threads) and the utilization is ~20-40% on each core. As the connections are accepted, the server asks the client for a bunch of data and then performas a bunch of database entries.

I moved the server application and SQL database to a small database and  medium server instance on Amazon AWS.

The Amazon Medium server(EC2) is 1 virtual core and 2 ECU's. From what I can tell it only has 1 thread.(from performance monitor)

If I try to connect 1000 clients over 35 seconds to the medium server. After ~650 connections i start to receive *Connect failed(b) No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it*.

Looking at performance monitor, I noticed that the CPU utilization is only ~10-15%.

I am guessing that the core is not getting loaded because it is trying to handle a huge queue of connections, of small operations and does not provide enough load to increase CPU usage, since the server only has 1 virtual core.

Does anyone have any experience with this, does my theory make sense? I am stuck at a hardware limitation? (need to bump up the server size?)

If not, any ideas how to get more utilization and support more/quicker connections?

Does anyone have experience with this?

EDIT:

I upgraded my instance on Amazon EC2 to the High CPU Extra Large instance.

The Instance now has 8 cores and 20 ECU's.

I am experiencing the same problem, I get No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it after ~600 connections.

Comment: Are you handling the "asks the client for a bunch of data and then performas a bunch of database entries" part on a seperate thread?  If not then you could be backlogged just from the db I/O time.

Comment: Latency to the database may be the cause, try disabling the database access and just return dummy data, that may show you if it's the network/machine or the database.

Comment: I will double check. As soon as I get the socket I call EndAccept() and get the client socket. I call BeginAccept() right away. Then I call waitForData() which is asych and when wait for data receives data from the client is does db processing on a separate thread. I am thinking the Medium instance from EC2 (1 virtual core and 2 ECU's) only has 1 thread. Which might be the problem. But my CPU utilization is very low on the core..

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Same problem with database disabled

Comment: What OS are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue. I upgraded my Instance to use PIOPS. I also used a better internet connection locally, as my old upload rate was too slow to support sending all the data and connections.

With these 2 changes I am able to create 5K+ TCP connections locally and connect to the server no problem.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem as you were, as per my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985361/websocket-server-stops-accepting-after-600-connections ..Do you know which one of these factors fixed the problem, or was it both? Thanks for any help

Comment: Answered my own question.. for me, trying a different network from the client side worked. Must have been the internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the Amazon servers are configured to allow that many open TCP connections. In windows you have to set the server to allow connection by adding a registry entry for Max allowed TCP connections.

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be utilizing multiple cores while you were running it locally. Have you made changes in the code while you moved it to single core?. I have seen similar case in my application when I was testing with dummy user creation and programmatically making them access the application at same time. After certain number , I used to get connection dropped / not able to access.

If your requirement is for heavy utilization, you can go with higher config EC2 and get the reserved instance  ( if you are looking to use it for long time), which might cost you very economic. Also, try using cloudfront , loadbalancer( if you have 2/more instances). they will definitely improve the number of users you can handle currently. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes my code was using multiple cores locally. Moving to Amazon, since I only have 1 core I think this is the problem. However, even with 1 core would my CPU utilization be so low?

Comment: you said on one core of local setup, you were getting 20-40% cpu utilization, while handling 5k connections, so - per core around 1.25k /core right ? so here in EC2 you are getting just 600 simultaneous connections, after which its breaking.. I would suggest you to make changes in code and utilize single core upto at least 70%. try also with cloufront, or go with higher config ec2.

Comment: thats explains it all. either make changes in code to utilize 70% of cpu.. or go with multi core , with hyper threading, reserved instance.