# Websocket server stops accepting after ~600 connections

Tags: windows, tcp, websocket

I'm running a websocket server (command line program) off port 9000 on a Windows 2008 server. I can't seem to figure out why it will not accept more than about 600 concurrent connections. Testing on my local machine, I can create thousands of concurrent connections. But on the server, I get the following error after about 600:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I have tried adjusting registry entries for the max port number, and turning off the firewall to no avail. I have also tried a different websocket server implementation. Is there some other setting I need to change?

edit: I tried this on a Linux server as well with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

It seems to be my client side internet connection. By running the same tests on a different network from the client side, I can create thousands of connections.